# Control firebase push notification in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my listener for firebase push notifications. The behaviour I want is that when a push notification is received in the background state, I want to stop the device from showing it and instead show it as local notification. I have already implemented this below in the foreground state. I want same functionality in `setBackgroundMessageHandler` but it displays two notifications and also reopens the app (which I don't want).

I am using topics notifications

```
export const NotificationListener = navigation => {

  messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
    console.log(
      'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
      remoteMessage?.notification,
    );
  });

  messaging()
    .getInitialNotification()
    .then(remoteMessage => {
      if (remoteMessage) {
        console.log(
          'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
          remoteMessage?.notification,
        );
      }
    });

  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
    // let title = remoteMessage?.notification?.title;
    // let body = remoteMessage?.notification?.body;
    // PushNotification.localNotification({
    //   channelId: 'burque_channel_id',
    //   title: title,
    //   message: body,
    // });
  });

  messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log('notifications on foreground state..', remoteMessage);
    let title = remoteMessage?.notification?.title;
    let body = remoteMessage?.notification?.body;
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      channelId: 'burque_channel_id',
      title: title,
      message: body,
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the device receives a message with a `notification` element while the app is backgrounded, it displays that notification before invoking any application code. There is no way to change this behavior.

If you want to fully control the display of the message in your application code, you should send a message with **only** a `data` element.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).