# How to handle firebase background message in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to manage the title and body of notification and show my own instead of main one in notification bar for specific type of notification. I did it in foreground and it work perfectly but when I called onBackground method to handle background notification it throw this error.

```
E/flutter (14578): #2      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage
package:firebase_messaging/src/messaging.dart:73
E/flutter (14578): #3      FirebaseNotification.firebaseCloudMessagingListeners
package:teaticchat/Utils/FirebaseNotificatonServices.dart
```

can anyone help me with this.
Here is my onBackground method:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((message)async{
   print(message.notification);
});
```

Comment: How does your `onBackground()` method look like

Comment: So the notification is supposed to show Title and Body from firebase?? Or what do you actually need to achieve?

Comment: Notification messages are handled by the system when the app is not active. There's no way to change this. I just answered a similar question for React, so have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77132041/209103

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
I only want to show other text for some specific title if I receive those titles from firebase messaging. There was something on doc that you can manage them by onBackground message method of FirebaseMessaging package but when I use that it throw that Exception